# Microsoft Semblio

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Has anyone used the [Microsoft Semblio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/learningspace/semblio/Default.aspx) to build a training or education product yet?  If so, how was the developer experience and/or the user experience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. I've used it extensively (I work in L&D) in testing functionally and appropriateness for a corporate learning environment but finally decided against it. Some reasons:

1. The learning curve for average
   instructional designers was too
   high. If it was meant for a
   dedicated half-developer/half-ISD 
   person to somehow work in this  SDK
   and design great e-Learning, the
   Vision/Scope of Semblio was  way off
   base. It's a good product for
   developers - it's just that  that
   profile of person is not
   particularly good at creating
   e-Learning/CBTs.
2. The Education PG (the group that
   produces this product) has had quite
   a few product blotches and
   non-ships. This one actually made it
   out the door, but it isn't getting
   the uptake that EdPG was expecting.
   It's likely going to be relegated to
   "well, we tried but nobody wanted
   it" in the fight between all
   internal academic-focused groups
   (Public Sector sales,
   Partners-in-Learning, EdPG,
   Unlimited Potential, etc.) - so my
   guess is that support will fall
   away.
3. Most important was the decision to
   use WPF instead of Silverlight. This
   not a slight against WPF, which is a
   fine technology, but it tells me two
   things: This is a Windows-platform
   play given that education uses
   Windows/Mac/Linux. WinClient
   Platform-Adoption products tend to
   fall away pretty quickly at MSFT
   (with the exception of Visual
   Studio/Expressions).  2) There will
   be deployment concerns of the .Net
   framework and the Semblio packages. On this point, it makes
   an assumption that most schools are
   running semi-sophisticated IT
   departments that have a good deployment server.

Semblio could have just as easily been created for Silverlight and made into a true [Adobe Captivate](http://www.Adobe.com/Captivate) or [Articulate](http://www.articulate.com) competitor. It could have utilized an organizations existing assets, such as Office, for e-Learning creation.

It was for these reasons I decided against using it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Do you have any pearls of wisdom on the learner experience with Semblio content?

Comment: The user experience with what we beta tested was average. It wasn't about the eLearning creative treatment itself, which had non-descript feedback (gradient widgets and table of content controls don't really impress folks). It was more about the impressive experience from start to finish - meaning they had to find and launch the program, figure out its interface and then nav through the whole thing. They didn't find it to be better or worse than other eLearning they've gone through, even with extra-special WPF widgets created with the Semblio API. It was immersive, but not impressive for them.

Answer (score 3):

I have not used Semblio but i have used another similar product that came from Macromedia and then went to Adobe, Coursebuilder and i have been involved with development an deployment of Moodle, a cross platform VLE (Virtual Learning Environment).

Coursebuilder suffered/suffers from the same problem as Semblio appears to and that is the people who can build the courses from a technical standpoint do not involve themselves directly in course design/teaching design and vice versa.

The technical maix of the two seemed fine but in the end it came down to as Otaku says above "well, we tried but nobody wanted it".

I often feel that when this type of product is designed or mooted that the people backing seem to mistake on-line learning with massively polished 3d whiz bang graphical tools and mistake presentation for substance.

As a counter example Moodle is an FOSS install it yourself tool designed for educators to use. With access to a server on an "amateur" basis a teacher or college lecturer with minimal skills and a couple of night reading can install and configure Moodle and have course up and running for students in a matter of days, or even hours. It can of course look amazingly clunky compared with the likes of CourseBuilder and or Semblio but it get get massive usage and support. Moodle is of course cross platform and will run on relatively low levels of connection and computer spec as all you need to power it (in most cases) is a browser.

As well as that the usage of the tools like Semblio while perfectly capable of producing perfectly good learning material and educational tools often lack the other requisites. How do you deliver the learning? Is it part of a larger course and how do you integrate it? How do you mark it? etc.

I sometimes think that the like of Semblio and CourseBuilder are there to sell the technology, Flash, Silverlight etc as opposed to being a real educational delivery tool. But i apologise if that view seems biased.

Comment: Thank you for echoing Otaku's sentiments and pointing out that Semblio is not a complete solution.